# A set S is infinite if and only if for all n∈ℕ, there exists a subset of S whose cardinality is n.

Tags: proof-verification, cardinals

Theorem:A set S is infinite if and only if for all n∈ℕ, there exists a subset of S whose cardinality is n.

I think their necessary condition $\rightarrow$ proof is correct. I won't add their forwards proof because it seems tedtious.

Proof
I found this from proof wiki

https://proofwiki.org/w/index.php?title=Set_is_Infinite_iff_exist_Subsets_of_all_Finite_Cardinalities&oldid=276524

and it's wrong I think. I'm looking to confirm that their proof is wrong.  I wrote my own and wanted proof verification.

$\leftarrow$

> Sufficient Condition  Suppose that for all n∈ℕ, there exists a subset
>   of S whose cardinality is n.
>
> Assume that S is finite.
>
> Let N=|S|.
>
> As N∈ℕ it follows that N+1∈ℕ.
>
> By hypothesis, there exists a subset T⊆S whose cardinality is N+1.
>
> From Cardinality of Subset of Finite Set, |S|≥|T|.
>
> But then |S|=N≥N+1=|T|, which contradicts the fact that N
>
> From this contradiction it follows that S can not be finite.

I disagree that T, a proper subset of S, has a cardinality greater than S. By definition, a proper subset cannot have a cardinality greater or equal to that set that it is a proper subset of, that is Card T

I disagree that by hypothesis, $\exists$ a subset T $\subseteq$ S whose cardinality is N+1. Card T should be less than S. since T is subset of S.

I think their proof by contradiction is a mistake and direct proof is better.

I think a better way is to

Pf.
Assume for all n∈ℕ, there exists a proper subset of S whose cardinality is n. Try to show that S is infinite by induction.

Base case is the case when the proper subset of S called T is of cardinality 1. 
If you think the natural numbers start at 0, then consider the empty set which is a subset of every set and Card 0 + Card $S\setminus \emptyset$ = Card S.

If you think natural numbers start at 1 then,

Card $S\setminus T$ + Card T = Card S.

Inductive step:
Assume
for all sets with cardinality denoted by the number 1<=j<=k where j is the cardinality of T the equation Card $S\setminus T$ + Card T = Card S holds.  Show this equation works for k+1 being the cardinality of set T.

When we add an element to set T, which is a proper subset of S Card T is increased by one. the cardinality of $S\setminus T$ decreases by one, so we end up adding and subtracting one making no net difference. the equation holds for when k+1 is the cardinality of T.

For inductive step:

(Card $S\setminus T$) $-1$ + Card T +1 = Card S

$\Longleftrightarrow$

$x$ $\in$ S.

Card $((S\setminus T) \setminus {{x}})$  + Card (T $\cup$ {x}) = Card S

Therefore S is infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I disagree that by hypothesis, ∃ a subset T ⊆ S whose cardinality is N+1. Card T should be less than S. since T is subset of S.

Right, that's why it's a proof by contradiction. The original assumption lead to a conclusion that is clearly false, hence the assumption is false. It simply *is* the case that, by hypothesis, $S$ has a subset of cardinality $N+1$. For it is a proeprty of $S$ that it has a subset of cardinality $n$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$. Since $N+1\in\mathbb N$, $S$ has a subset of cardinality $N+1$. There's no flaw in this reasoning. It's also true that we need $\vert T \vert \leq \vert S \vert$, and so we reach a contradiction, meaning that $S$ must be infinite.

Further, proving the result by induction doesn't really work, since your goal isn't to prove that a certain statement holds for all natural numbers.

Comment: The necessary condition of the proof $\rightarrow$ was proven using induction. Doesn't that mean the sufficent condition is also proving using induction?

Comment: The necessary condition is If a set S is infinite then for all n∈ℕ, there exists a subset of S whose cardinality is n.                The sufficient condition is  if for all n∈ℕ, there exists a subset of S whose cardinality is n, then s is infinite. Don't I need to use induction to show S is infinite?

Comment: Why is it that sometimes the necessary and sufficent conditions seem like exact rewinds of each other but at other times they're not mirror images of each other?

Comment: There's no reason to expect that the necessary and sufficient conditions will usually have similar proofs. Sometimes they will, sometimes they won't. Here, it shouldn't be too hard to see that one direction can utilize induction and the other can't, since in only one direction you're trying to prove that something holds for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: I'll attempt to negate this: "A set S is infinite if and only if for all n∈ℕ, there exists a subset of S whose cardinality is n". A set S is finite iff there exists n∈ℕ, for all subsets of S, the subsets of S cardinality is not n? Can you verify whether I'm correct?

Comment: The negation of $p\iff q$ is $p\iff \lnot q$. Why do you want to negate the original theorem in the first place?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what a finite set is in regards to what subsets or lack of subsets they have and what the cardinalities of their subsets would be. I'm trying to understand the definition of a finite set is

Comment: A finite set is any set in bijection with some (unique) $\{0,1,...,n-1\}$ where $n\in\mathbb N$. A finite set of cardinality $n$ has at least one subset with cardinality $m$ for each $0\leq m \leq n$. Conversely, if $T$ is a subset of some finite set $S$, then $\vert T \vert \leq \vert S \vert$ (this is true regardless of whether $S$ is finite, actually).